# Farther extending ApplicationUser class in ASP.NET MVC5 Identity system

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, tph

I'm creating a simple application for university where a student can make some type of request which is then processed by an employee of particular speciality.

I would like to use default MVC5 identity system and to extend the ApplicationUser class using TPH pattern. So I added the common properties to the ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

then I created two classes which inherits the ApplicationUser:

```
public class Student : ApplicationUser
    {
        public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
        public bool Monitor { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    }

public class Employee : ApplicationUser
    {
        public virtual EmployeeSpeciality EmployeeSpeciality { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    }
```

what I currently want is to make both types of users register as a base Identity and to keep both in a single table as in the [inheritance example on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

As I thought, it would be enough to initialize user var in AccountController which is then passes to the UserManager as a Student or as an Employee. But after trying to register as a Student i'm getting this exception:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'PersonalNumber'.
Invalid column name 'Monitor'.
Invalid column name 'EmployeeSpeciality_Id'.
Invalid column name 'Group_Id'.
```

My context class:

```
public class EntityContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public EntityContext()
            : base("DbConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

and a part of controller's action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new Student()
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Email = model.Email
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I tried setting ApplicationClass to an abstract class, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The problem wasn't in the code itself. I simply haven't dropped (or updated) the database after making these changes to the model. After it everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

@Dragonheart: I tried this repro and it would work fine if you remove the DBSet declarations in you context class. The IdentityDbContext would handle you TPH pattern and add a Discriminator column in the table to differentiate the child classes.

Comment: After your comment I tried to reproduce evertything (because I've already moved to the TPT pattern by holding Student and Employee in their own tables and having a navigation property in ApplicationUser for both of them) and it works even without removing DBSet's for Student and Employee. The real problem was kinda silly - I simply forgot to drop or update the DB via migrations. It's a facepalm, I know. Thx for your attention anyway :)

Comment: @Dragonheart If this is what solved your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it, for the benefit of future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As `ApplicationUser` is inherited from `IdentityUser`, remove it from your `DbContext` class. On the other hand, there is no need to create an `abstract` class (you can create if you prevent from creating a user except from `Student` or `Employee` classes. For more information you might have a look at [Table-per-Hierarchy](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

For `Register` part, try something like that:

```
Student user = new Student
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
    Email = model.Email
};
var result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Why are you creating a new `ApplicationUser` instance, just to throw it away on the next line, replacing it with a `Student` instance?

Comment: I was using this code at the same Controller for both type of users but for this situation there is no need to create ApplicationUser instance. 


and for this reason I wanted to create a shared property. Thanks for informing...