# MVC5 multiple user types - prefer base class or property for ApplicationUser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

My application will have 3 types of users, for example IndividualUser, BusinessUser and AdminUser. There might be quite a few distinct properties on each of these models.

I have seen a couple of posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627222/1778169), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062981/f)) that advocate deriving these classes from the ApplicationUser class that comes with the MVC5 template. Like this:

```
IndividualUser : ApplicationUser
{
  string FirstName {get;set;}
  string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

However... I understand that this setup results in all user types sharing the same table in the DB.  Because of this I am anticipating problems when some user types have distinct properties that must not be nullable (such as DateTime fields).

Therefore I am considering using the ApplicationUser class as a property on more advanced user models. Like this:

```
IndividualUser
{
  ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get;set;}
  string FirstName {get;set;}
  string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

This seems more appropriate to me, because each of the 3 user types will have a number of distinct properties. Yet I have never seen this approach recommended - I'm wondering if there is a reason for this?

I'm not particularly confident in using the membership in MVC5 so I'm not sure what the consequences or implications of each approach would be.

Comment: "Because of this I am anticipating problems when some user types have distinct properties that must not be nullable" you can use TPT or TPC approach to eliminate that problem

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into that. It seem to be pretty straight forward. Would you recommend that approach over using ApplicationUser as a property?